# Flink job submission failed for akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException

Tags: apache-flink

Job submission failed for `akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException`, I have tried to set `akka.ask.timeout: "60s"`, still failed for the same error. Any idea?

```
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://flink/user/dispatcher#-1594246162]] after [10000 ms]. Message of type [org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.LocalFencedMessage]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$2.apply(AskSupport.scala:635)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$2.apply(AskSupport.scala:635)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:648)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:205)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:328)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:279)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:283)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)
```

Comment: Does your jobmanager can see all task-managers (check at the web-ui). Where do you run your cluster? K8? Maybe something wrong with the port config?

Comment: Changing the `Akka.ask.timeout` is not always the answer, since Flink does override this on multiple occasions. In this case you can try `web.timeout` or `akka.client.timeout`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue [FLINK-11143](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11143). Hope it could be resolved soon.